# Device Not booting into Odin mode

Tags: samsung, odin, samsung-galaxy-grand

I have an sm-g350h and when I try booting into Odin mode, It comes back to the normal mode.
I power off my phone and press home + volume down + power.
It boots into the stock os.

Comment: `adb reboot bootloader` should work

Comment: The command worked!